# How do I loop through products when tracking orders with Google Analytics Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I have a web shop for which I want to track orders. I have successfully set up Google Analytics and pulled test data when orders are finalized, so I get information about the transaction and about the product ordered.

Naturally, I want to pull data from several products in an order, and here is where my problem arises. Whenever I insert a loop I get a template error:

> Too many characters in character literal

The script I am using is this:

```html
<script>
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');

  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '@GetString("Ecom:Order.ID")',
    'affiliation': 'Online Store',
    'revenue': '@GetDouble("Ecom:Order.Price.PriceWithVAT")',
    'shipping': '@GetDouble("Ecom:Order.ShippingFee.Price")',
    'tax': '@GetDouble("Ecom:Order.Price.VAT")'
  });

  @foreach(LoopItem orderline in GetLoop("OrderLines")) {
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '@orderline.GetString("Ecom:Product.ID")',
      'name': '@orderline.GetString("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.ProductName")',
      'price': '@orderline.GetDouble("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.UnitPrice.Price")',
      'quantity': '@orderline.GetString("Ecom:Order:OrderLine.Quantity")'
    });
  }
  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Is there something wrong in the way I use this script? It seems like there is only an error when I try to loop through products.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this - my problem was that I had added the product ID in the `ecommerce:addItem` when instead I should have added the Order ID from `ecommerce:addTransaction` so it can link the products to the transaction. If you want to add the product ID, use `'sku' : [product id]`.